# Can't get results from a IQueryable

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following code in Linq to Entity:

```
var policy= from pol in conn.Policy
            where pol.Product.DESCRIPTION=="someProduct"
            SELECT pol;
```

Then, the table Policy, has some dependencies for a table called Entity. If I do this:

```
foreach(Policy p in policy){
    if(!p.Entity.IsLoaded) p.Entity.Load();
    IEnumerable<Entity> entities= from ent in p.Entity
                                  Where ent.EntityType.DESCRIPTION=="SomeEntityType"
                                  select ent;
    Console.Writeline(entities.ElementAt(0).NAME);
}
```

It says, "Object not set to an instance", but if I do:

```
foreach(Policy p in policy){
    if(!p.Entity.IsLoaded) p.Entity.Load();

    foreach(Entity et in p.Entity)Console.Write(et.NAME);

}
```

It works!
Can anyone tell me why?

Thank you, Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's because your LINQ statement isn't returning any values, so `entities` is null.

Your second example works because you're not trying to filter the results.

Do you have some entities that have the `DESCRIPTION` set to exactly the string (including case)?